# Find an isomorphism $D: Hom_R(R^p, R^q) \longrightarrow R^{p\times q}$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-space-isomorphism

I know this would be really basic, but I'm currently struggling to describe the proper isomorphism that fulfills the following description for natural $p$ and $q$:
$$D: Hom_R(R^p, R^q) \longrightarrow R^{p\times q}$$

I can't find one, plus how would one prove it's an isomorphism (I'm more sure here: we just need to prove it's a linear function and a bijective one). Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Let $e_i$ for $i<p$ be a base for $R^p$ and $\pi_j:R^q\to R$ for $j<q$ be the canonical projection.
Then
\begin{align}
&\operatorname{Hom}(R^p,R^q)\to R^{p\times q}&
&\varphi\mapsto((\pi_j\circ\varphi)(e_i):i<p\land j<q)
\end{align}
is a module isomorphism.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I just got a couple of questions:
- what is the canonical projection?
- is $\pi_j$ a function in the given context?
- how is that an isomorphism and what defines a module isomorphism?

I guess I'm short on terminology and experience... thank you again!